# Javascript Output is giving empty response

Tags: javascript, html, binary

I'm making a binary calculator. Following is my javascript code:

```
// let operator = document.getElementsByClassName('operator');
let plus = document.getElementById('btnSum');
let minus = document.getElementById('btnSub');
let into = document.getElementById('btnMul');
let divide = document.getElementById('btnDiv');
let resultBox = document.getElementById('res');

var val1;
var val2;
var clicked = false;

plus.addEventListener("click", function(){
    clicked = true;
    let middleOperator = '+';
    resultBox.innerHTML += ' + ';
});

minus.addEventListener("click", function(){
    clicked = true;
    let middleOperator = '-';
    resultBox.innerHTML += ' - ';
});

into.addEventListener("click", function(){
    clicked = true;
    let middleOperator = '*';
    resultBox.innerHTML += ' * ';
});

divide.addEventListener("click", function(){
    clicked = true;
    let middleOperator = '/';
    resultBox.innerHTML += '/';
});

function pushZero(){
    if(clicked){
        //if middleOperator is pressed
        resultBox.innerHTML += '0';
        val2 = resultBox.innerText;
    }else{
        //if middleOperator is not pressed
        resultBox.innerHTML += '0';
        val1 = resultBox.innerText;
    }    
}

function pushOne(){
    if(clicked){
        //if middleOperator is pressed
        resultBox.innerHTML += '1';
        val2 = resultBox.innerText;
    }else{
        //if middleOperator is not pressed
        resultBox.innerHTML += '1';
        val1 = resultBox.innerText;
    }    
}

//passing array to this function
function binaryToNum(a){
    let num = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
       num +=  a[i]*Math.pow(2, a.length-i-1);
    }

    return num;
}

//Function to convert a number to binary
function numToBinary(x){
    var s='';
    let n;
    while(x>=1){
        n = x%2;
        s += `${n}`;
        x /= 2;
    }
 
    return s;
}

function result(middleOperator){
    var ans;
    var num1 = binaryToNum(val1);
    var num2 = binaryToNum(val2);

    if(middleOperator == '+'){
        ans = num1 + num2;
    }

    if(middleOperator == '-'){
        ans = num1 - num2;
    }

    if(middleOperator == '*'){
        ans = num1*num2;
    }

    if(middleOperator == '/'){
        ans = num1/num2;
    }

    var output = numToBinary(ans);

    console.log(output);
    resultBox.innerHTML = output;
}
```

When I'm trying to display the result it shows **empty output**.
While assigning any random *string* to the output displays the same on the screen.(Thus there is no issue on Html or Dom side).
Also when I'm *console.log()* gives an empty output. How to solve this?

Comment: How is the `result()` function called?

Comment: `middleOperator ` is not in global scope

Comment: Also, you can ass also the relevant HTML and create an executable snippet

Comment: `middleOperator` must be a global variable like `val1` and `val2`, not a `let` or parameter. Currently your `ans` is always undefined.

Comment: `middleOperator` is passed as a parameter to `result()` so it does not necessarily have to be global. It all depends on how `result()` is called. OP needs to create a [mcve].